# libgdx font.setscale gives giant values

Tags: java, text, libgdx

I'm using libgdx but using the BitmapFont class give me a really giant text.
Even if I set the scale to really small values (0.1f), the font still is rendered at giant sizes.

Libgdx documentation doesn't explain what are the normal values I should use.

My screen resolution is 320w/480h

[image: Giant text]

Edit: Source code:

[MyGdxGame](http://pastebin.com/q8386VWw) MyGdxGame class

[Map class](http://pastebin.com/7p1pLYME) Map Class (the board that contains the label)

Comment: where do you initialize your bitmapfont object? post relevant code please

Comment: In the create function I simply set f_time_left = new BitmapFont(), is nothing advanced actually.

Comment: what's the width and height of your camera? (I'm not talking about your screen resolution)...

Comment: 480 height 320 width (3:2 aspect ratio)

Comment: you need to post your code in order to help you (at least the `create()` or a relevant constructor/method), is difficult to know what is happening...

Comment: sorry, source coded added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a very small camera:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
```

your camera doesn't have a `320 x 480` dimension, it has one of `1 x 1.5`, so even a small font won't fit your view because fonts work in pixel.

A fast solution is to set camera to:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(320f, 480f);
```

Or, if you don't want to modify this camera, add another with a bigger resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using it in wrong way , try this , I have done it this way.

```
public static BitmapFont font;

font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"));
font.getData().setScale(.3f, -.3f);
```

you can set this value to setScale(.1f, -.1f); // it would give you really small font.

Comment: I created a debug function to set the scale and the text just dissapear if the scale value is less than 0.04 and it simply reappears if I set it bigger than 0.04. Having into account 0.04 is my screen height, is pretty weird.

Comment: Scale value 0.04 has nothing to do with your screen height 0.04! One is in percentage and one is a dimension.